# Uniform convergence, Pointwise Equicontinuity and Uniform Equicontinuity for functon.

Tags: analysis, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity, equicontinuity

I am  trying to answer the following question:

---

Define $f_n(s)=s^n$ where $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Is the family of functions $\{f_n\}$:

1. Uniformly convergent
2. Pointwise Equicontinuous
3. Uniformly Equicontinuous

---

I think I have managed to show that they are not uniformly convergent, but am struggling with the other two. Currently, I believe the answers are No, Yes, No. But I'm not sure and I keep getting confused with all the $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. Please could someone help me answer this.

Comment: please state the definition of pointwise equicontinuity and uniformly equicontinuity and tell us what you have tried.

Comment: I am using these definitions from the wiki page on Equicontinuity:

$\{f_n\}$ is pointwise equicontinuous if $\forall x_0 \in [0,1]$, $\forall\varepsilon>0$, $\exists\delta>0$ such that $\forall f \in F, \forall x$, $d(x_0, x)<\delta \implies d(f(x_0), f(x))<\varepsilon$.

$\{f_n\}$ is uniformly equicontinuous if $\forall\varepsilon>0$, $\exists\delta>0$ such that $\forall f \in F$, $\forall x_1, x_2 \in X,d\left(x_1, x_2\right)<\delta \implies d(f(x_1), f(x_2))<\varepsilon$.

I've tried substituting the function in question into these definitions, but I get a bit confused after that.